# how to turn Google analytics on or off depending on user log in?

Tags: google-analytics

I currently have website (vb.net) that uses google analytics and it has been working fine. What i want to do is turn off GA when the employees of my company log in and turn in on when the clients use it. Each login has a unique id so the first thing that i thought of was to just check the id and add/remove the GA code depending on who logs in. I'm not sure if doing this will affect the stats in any way. Are there other ways to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your use case, it could be better to utilize this data by placing it within a [custom variable](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables), saying if the member is an employee or a regular user. Within the reporting you could then segment the traffic based on value. In most cases this will be the better option as you won't have an inflated drop off rate at the login screen.

If you're still needing to abort the calls, you have a few options:

1. Add the JavaScript `window['ga-disable-UA-#######-##'] = true;` on the page. This will need to be done before you call the normal Google Analytics code.
2. Add logic to fire or not include the entire Google Analytics code block if the user is within a certain group or has a certain ID. This will obviously depend on what language you're developing in.